# Source files not being compiled using Makefile rules

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile

```
CXX       = g++
CXXFLAGS  = -c -g -pg -Wall -Wextra
LINK      = g++
TARGET    = ../../Binaries/tests
SOURCES   := ../Src/$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJS_DIR  := ../Objects
OBJS      = $(sort $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJS_DIR)/%.o, $(patsubst %.c, $(OBJS_DIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SOURCES)))))

tests: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
  $(LINK) $? -o $@

$(OBJS): $(SOURCES)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $? -o $@
```

which, when run using `make tests` (or simply just `make`), gives the following output:

```
g++  -o ../../Binaries/tests
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../../Binaries/tests] Error 4
```

This seems to me that make is trying to link the files (that don't yet exist) without checking the rule for `$(OBJS)`. My goal is to have a Makefile that is entirely self sufficient, being able to find the `*.cpp` file in ../Src and the `*.o` file (that it will generate itsef) in ../Objects, however the rule I've written doesn't seem to be working out that way. Can anyone please tell me where I've gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is on the following line:

```
SOURCES   := ../Src/$(wildcard *.cpp)
```

It should be something like this instead:

```
SOURCES   := $(wildcard ../Src/*.cpp)
```

Also transforming sources into objects could be rewritten as follows:

```
OBJS      := $(SOURCES:../Src/%.cpp=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)
```

Finally the compilation rule is usually implemented through [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o : ../Src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```